# Tikz path crossing over first node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, tikz-path

I'm working on a Python script to automatically draw pinout diagrams for IC's with Tikz. An example drawing with the TeX file obtained are shown below.

As you can see I'm almost done except for a small detail; the path joining the nodes overlaps the first node (PA1, PA2, etc.)

I've tried numerous things without success as Tikz seems to behave weirdly with my code.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,external}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,scale=0.8,
    pin/.style={draw,rectangle,rounded corners=1mm,fill=gray!50,minimum width=8mm},
    label/.style={draw,rectangle,rounded corners=1mm,minimum width=8mm}]

    % Constants
    \def\pps{8} % pps = pins per side
    \def\size{\pps * 0.75}
    \def\halfsize{\size / 2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\side{2 * \size / 1.41}

    % Draw IC shape and name
    \node at (0,0) [minimum size=\side cm,diamond,fill=black!60,rounded corners=5mm] () {\LARGE STM32F103C8};
    \node at (0,\size / 1.8) [circle,inner sep=\size / 2,fill=black] () {};

    % Create pin nodes with numberings
    \newcounter{pin}\setcounter{pin}{0}

    \foreach \y/\angle/\dir in {-\halfsize/-45/1,-\halfsize/45/1,\halfsize/-45/-1,\halfsize/45/-1}{
        \begin{scope}[transform shape,rotate around={\angle:(0,0)}]
            \foreach \x in {1,...,\pps}
                \stepcounter{pin}
                \node at (\y - \dir * 0.3,{\dir * (\size / 2 - \size / (\pps + 1) * \x)}) [pin] (\thepin-0) {\large\thepin};
        \end{scope}
    }

    % Begin pin functions data
    % Pin 1
    \node[label,left=of 1-0,fill=gray] (1-1) {PA1};
    \node[label,left=of 1-1,fill=green] (1-2) {TIM1{\_}CH1};
    \node[label,left=of 1-2,fill=orange] (1-3) {ADC1{\_}CH2};
    \draw (1-0) [out=180,in=0] to (1-1)  -- (1-2)  -- (1-3) ; % <---- Problem is here

    % Pin 2
    \node[label,left=of 2-0,fill=gray] (2-1) {PA2};
    \node[label,left=of 2-1,fill=blue] (2-2) {DAC2};
    \node[label,left=of 2-2,fill=white] (2-3) {I2C{\_}SDL};
    \node[label,left=of 2-3,fill=orange] (2-4) {USART6{\_}RX};
    \draw (2-0) [out=180,in=0] to (2-1)  -- (2-2)  -- (2-3)  -- (2-4) ;

    %%%%%%%%
    % Rest of pins omitted to reduce clutter
    %%%%%%%%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! E.g. `\draw (1-0) to[out=180,in=0]  (1-1) (1-1) -- (1-2)  to (1-3) ; ` fixes it.

Comment: Thanks! I never would have guessed to repeat the (1-1).

Comment: Is your script opensourced somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple fix is to duplicate the first `to` node, i.e. to say

```
\draw (1-0) to[out=180,in=0] (1-1) (1-1) -- (1-2) to (1-3) ;
```

Please note that a `to` path, which relies on the `topaths` library, which however gets autoloaded, behaves somewhat different from `--`, not only in that you can bend the paths. The effect you are observing is that the `to` path connect to the correct point on the border (see the command `\pgfpointshapeborder` on p, 1123 of pgfmanual v3.1.4b), and then goes on from there. If you are saying that this behavior is not fully symmetrical, I agree.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,external}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,scale=0.8,
    pin/.style={draw,rectangle,rounded corners=1mm,fill=gray!50,minimum width=8mm},
    label/.style={draw,rectangle,rounded corners=1mm,minimum width=8mm}]

    % Constants
    \def\pps{8} % pps = pins per side
    \def\size{\pps * 0.75}
    \def\halfsize{\size / 2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\side{2 * \size / 1.41}

    % Draw IC shape and name
    \node at (0,0) [minimum size=\side cm,diamond,fill=black!60,rounded corners=5mm] () {\LARGE STM32F103C8};
    \node at (0,\size / 1.8) [circle,inner sep=\size / 2,fill=black] () {};

    % Create pin nodes with numberings
    \newcounter{pin}\setcounter{pin}{0}

    \foreach \y/\angle/\dir in {-\halfsize/-45/1,-\halfsize/45/1,\halfsize/-45/-1,\halfsize/45/-1}{
        \begin{scope}[transform shape,rotate around={\angle:(0,0)}]
            \foreach \x in {1,...,\pps}
                \stepcounter{pin}
                \node at (\y - \dir * 0.3,{\dir * (\size / 2 - \size / (\pps + 1) * \x)}) [pin] (\thepin-0) {\large\thepin};
        \end{scope}
    }

    % Begin pin functions data
    % Pin 1
    \node[label,left=of 1-0,fill=gray] (1-1) {PA1};
    \node[label,left=of 1-1,fill=green] (1-2) {TIM1{\_}CH1};
    \node[label,left=of 1-2,fill=orange] (1-3) {ADC1{\_}CH2};
    \draw (1-0) to[out=180,in=0]  (1-1) (1-1) -- (1-2)  -- (1-3) ; % <---- Problem is here

    % Pin 2
    \node[label,left=of 2-0,fill=gray] (2-1) {PA2};
    \node[label,left=of 2-1,fill=blue] (2-2) {DAC2};
    \node[label,left=of 2-2,fill=white] (2-3) {I2C{\_}SDL};
    \node[label,left=of 2-3,fill=orange] (2-4) {USART6{\_}RX};
    \draw (2-0) to[out=180,in=0] (2-1) (2-1)  -- (2-2)  -- (2-3)  -- (2-4) ;

    %%%%%%%%
    % Rest of pins omitted to reduce clutter
    %%%%%%%%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Already replied to your comment, but thanks again!